# JQuery Masonry Chrome 49

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, masonry

I have a problem with the latest version of Google Chrome 49 on a site that uses Masonry JavaScript.

I have a responsive web site at [www.citypointtrading.com](http://www.citypointtrading.com). The site has four width options which cause the 'masonry' to move around based on the available browser width.

When the site is shown in Chrome 49 with 1280px inner width or more, it is now all mis-aligned (the five boxes under the carousel).

This can only be reproduced in Google Chrome v49x (Windows and Mac). The same site looks fine in Google Canary, Safari, Firefox, IE etc.

Update: This is a new problem, the site was working fine in Chrome for many months, but has gone wrong only in the last few weeks. Please note that everything works fine in Chrome v51 (Canary) but hardly anyone is currently using that version.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Screenshot:
[The lower half of this screenshot shows the newly mis-aligned bricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6T6o.png)

Comment: do you really need 17 css classes attached to an element?

Comment: can you share screen for more details